# Swift SQL POST method - Why does it always create a response with <null> as the string?

Tags: sql, swift, postgresql, api, post

I'm trying to set up POST requests to connect my Swift Project to my SQL server. I found a lot of good resources on how to create the POST requests, and my code seems to create the request fine. However, it always returns a null string instead of the desired output string. How can I get the request to submit with the correct string?

My POST function:

```
func addString() {
    
    
    // declare the parameter as a dictionary that contains string as key and value combination. considering inputs are valid
    let parameters: [String: Any] = ["textstring":"Testing..."]
    
    // create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/strings")! // change server url accordingly
    
    // create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    // now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
    
    // add headers for the request
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") // change as per server requirements
    
    do {
        // convert parameters to Data and assign dictionary to httpBody of request
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    
    // create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Post Request Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        // ensure there is valid response code returned from this HTTP response
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode)
        else {
            print("Invalid Response received from the server")
            return
        }
        
        // ensure there is data returned
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("nil Data received from the server")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            // create json object from data or use JSONDecoder to convert to Model struct
            if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(jsonResponse)
                // handle json response
            } else {
                print("data maybe corrupted or in wrong format")
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    // perform the task
    task.resume()
}
```

My Object TextString that emulates the SQL table (Table "strings" has two columns: "id" (SERIAL PRIMARY KEY) and "textstring" (VARCHAR(255))

```
struct TextString: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
var id: Int
var textString: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "string_id"
    case textString = "textstring"
}}
```

My response output:

```
["string_id": 28, "textstring": <null>]
```

I'm thinking that the issue is with the serialization but the code is taken almost directly from a youtube video where the test cases are shown and they work. Does anyone know why the output returns "textstring" as null and not "Testing..."?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you print exactly your response with: `print("Response Stringified: \(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)") and share the output of that? Also, avoid generally `error.localizedDescription`, prefer `error`. It's to ensure that you really receive `textString` from your web API. Because that's what you send to it (in `httpBody`), but nothing here ensure that its sending it back to you.

Comment: The response I got was the following: Response Stringified: Optional("{\"string_id\":34,\"textstring\":null}")

Comment: So it's normal that your current code decode "null". So your issue is either with your API or either with the parameter you send...

Comment: Indeed. Found the typo in my API js file. Thanks a ton!